# J2EE + Struts2: Internationalization + Text Alignment

Tags: struts2

I want to know following about struts2:

1. Does internationalization works for Arabic & English? Any special considerations?
2. How can I change the alignment of text when locale is changed? For English it will be left aligned and for Arabic it will be right aligned?
3. How can I intercept (during) the change of locale so, that I can reload the information on the page which is being fetched from the database?
4. We also need to adjust some styles (css) since text with non-english alphabet/characters tend to take up space differently. Can we also “internationalize” css files?
5. Any working example with this scenario.

Any help will be great.

BR
SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes.  Make sure all characters in the message bundle are unicode escaped and not the actual characters.

2)  You can use the css or html: see http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html.  In out application, the Arabic is actually in the file in the proper direction so we did not have to change any styles.
3)  In Struts 2 you can set the session WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE.  See http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/localization.html and http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/i18n-interceptor.html

We had some trouble getting the language to store so we explicitly set that variable in the session

```
 Locale locale = (Locale) getSession().get("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE");
            if (!(locale instanceof Locale) || !locale.getLanguage().equals(new Locale(languageCode, "", "").getLanguage())) {
                getSession().put("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE", LocaleUtility.langToLocale(languageCode));
        }
```

4) Yes you can create mycss-ar.css, mycss-en.css and load the proper file based on the locale.

5)  Sorry I don't have any code to supply.

Comment: Thanks for response. I didn't get your point no. (2) "Arabic is actually in the file in the proper direction" we are going to make application from scratch so, how can I make such file? Can you share some example to clarify? Thanks. BR. SC.